# root path for typescript module resolution

Tags: typescript

I have two projects, which are using typescript. One is core project: moduleA, other one is business project: moduleB. ProjectB uses projectA's modules(ts files) located in `/scripts` folder. I want to specify module resolution root folder for projectB by `projectA/scripts`. Btw: Outs of the projects will be merged in production.

> Here is my file structure

```
├───projectA
│   │   index.html
│   │   systemjs.config.js
│   │   tsconfig.json
│   │
│   └───scripts
│       └───core
│           │   app.ts
│           │   components.ts
│           │
│           └───components
│                   dropdown.ts
│
└───projectB
    │   tsconfig.json
    │
    └───scripts
        └───pages
                page.ts
```

For example: In projectB's `page.ts` I want to import core modules like below.

```
import { DropdownList } from 'core/components';
```

Actually I'm doing it that way. JavaScript output of `page.ts` works fine. But I need to fix typescript compile error: `cannot find module "core/components"`.

I can do it by using `npm install/link projectA/scripts` in moduleB, or symlink.
But I need to solve it by option of `tsconfig.json` or some kind of declaration file/`references.d.ts`/. Because, We have hundreds of projects kind of projectB. `npm link` or symlink will be awkward work for us.

Is there any easy way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any easy way to do that

You need to use two things in your tsconfig.json :

- `rootDirs` to tell that `projectA/scripts` and `projectB/scripts` are right next to each other. (WARNING: does your compile time environment support it?).
- `baseUrl` if you want to use `core/components` instead of full relative paths `./core/components` (WARNING: does your module loader support it?).

Both of these are support in http://alm.tools/

Comment: Thank you @basarat. I heard about it. That is exactly what I need. I'm using typescript@1.7.3. Which version of typescript support `rootDirs` and `baseUrl` ?. Official document of [typescript compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) doesn't contain these options.

Comment: For more information in the mean time while these features are not yet documented in the official documentation, see this issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5039